# which java jdk to use?

Tags: android, java

I'm on the stage of learning java, and I have the following question. On a new machine withj CPUi5, 8GB RAM and Win7 x64, which version of JDK to install? Do I install x86 or x64 version?
Also, when is about to install Eclipse, which version is recomended for my case? x86 or x64?\

After some weeks of practicing with Java, I plan to go to Adroid dev.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend x86. I tried the x64 version back when it was fairly new, and its memory usage was enormous compared to the x86 version. I don't think there's any reason to use the x64 version for development in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose x86 in both cases. There is no need for x64 when doing Android development.

See also [Why should I use the 64-bit JDK over the 32-bit version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669778/why-should-i-use-the-64-bit-jdk-over-the-32-bit-version)

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a 32 bit Operating System, a 64 bit JDK or eclipse simply won't work.

If your OS is 64bit then it does not really matter, but you have to choose the same for both eclipse and the JDK because eclipse uses native libraries and you cannot mix 32 bit and 64 bit code in the same process.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to install x64 bit JDK and Eclipse x64. Android is developed based on x64 JDK. This can be a reason to choose this version.

Just to remember you that you have to install only JDK 5 or JDK 6 versions. In other case you'll have problems with Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have Win7 x86, if that is really the case then you have no option and need to use a 32-bit JDK. If you have Win7 64 bit then you can use either 32 or 64 bit. In my experience it doesn't matter which one you choose as long as you install the same Eclipse version.

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system is 32 bit so install 32 bit java and eclipse is not a problem for 32 bit or 64 bit.