# How to set Java Hotspot Server VM to client mode?

Tags: ubuntu, jvm, java, jvm-hotspot

[I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3669855/841064) that it's better to use 32 bit JDK on 64 bit Ubuntu so I installed `jdk-7u9-linux-i586.tar.gz` there with `libc6-i386` installed. When I run `java -version` the following info is printed:

```
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Also [I've read](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#compiler_types) that Client VM is better than Server VM at development computer. How do I set Hotspot to Client mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That may have been true 2 years ago, but 64-bit HotSpot works fine now, in development and in production, and has automatic pointer compression when you don't use a heap larger than around 24 GB.

As for the JIT mode, you select the server VM with -server (the default on most machines nowadays), and the client VM with -client.

Answer (score 2):

If anything is going to work it will be adding the `-client` option to the `java` command line.

However, according to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html), client VMs are not available for some platforms ... so you might find that `-client` is not accepted.  (The wording of the page does not make it entirely clear whether it is the instruction set of the hardware or the instruction set of the JDK / JRE that is critical ...)

---

> Also I've read that Client VM is better than Server VM at development computer.

I think it depends on whether you are using an IDE, and / or on the size of your builds.  For long builds and long IDE sessions, I'd expect a Server VM to be better.