# Start 32bit process on 64bit OS

Tags: c#, x86, 64-bit

My C# programm starts java application on 64bit OS (Windows). Java process is 64bit, how can i fix my launching code to start java process in 32bit?

My launching code:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.WorkingDirectory = ServerProperties.ServerWorkingDirectory;
info.FileName = "java"
info.Arguments = "some arguements"
ServerProcess = new Process();
ServerProcess.StartInfo = info;
ServerProcess.Start();
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Java process is 64bit" -- it would seem the JVM installed (or at least the one launched) is 64bit?

Comment: [There should be no problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783662/java-32-bit-vs-64-bit-compatibility) running your code on 64 bit, or do errors occur when you do?

Comment: c:\windows\syswow64\java.exe.  Why oh why?  Rhetorical question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a function of the process you're starting as opposed to the process that's starting it (i.e. the process that you're starting has to have been compiled/targeted to x86 as opposed to x86-64).

However, if both x86 and x86-64 *java.exe* are installed on the machine-in-question, you can probably hunt the x86 one down by looking in *Program Files (x86)* as opposed to *Program Files*.

Answer (score 0):

If you host your application in IIS you need enable x86 processes for pool of web app. Follows next steps:

1. Select the app pool for your web app.
2. Click **Advanced Settings** under Edit Application Pool on the right.
3. Change the value of **Enable 32-Bit Applications** to **True**.

Check next article for details - [Support of 32-bit applications in the 64-bit Windows environment](http://www.viva64.com/en/l/0002/)