# Eclipse RCP Plugin application crashes / freezes in windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, eclipse-plugin, swt

Eclipse RCP plugin application which has a mix of SWT and swing/awt windows getting crashed randomly in Windows 7 64 bit. Especially when i open SWING/awt dialogs. I cant able to debug even when i use -consoleLog in .ini file since it hangs as well along with the application.

The build details are given below.
JRE Version : 1.6_u04
NSIS Installer
.ini config : -vmargs-Xms64m -Xmx1024m

When i change the jre to 1.6_u18 it works fine. As update 18 provides win 7 support. But still some window freezes :(
If i reduce -Xmx value to 512m then it works properly.
Rarely Java Heap space problem also arises.

Pls guide me the proper way of fixing this issue.
Also let me know if we need to adjust Heap space in OS ?
The application installer comes along the with bundles of JRE 1.6_u04 itself. Will there be any issue of max heap size in windows 7?
Please advice !!

Comment: IF i increase JVM Size further the application crashed during the start up itself. So it clearly meant that OS Could not allocated the specified heap size.

Comment: Pls let me know how to increase the heap size in windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Swing and SWT often have threading/deadlock issues when using them in the same app.

Comment: If i decrease the Xmx value it works fine.. what could be the reason?

Comment: Do we need to build an eclipse plugin application with 64 bit as well?

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783662/java-32-bit-vs-64-bit-compatibility), that wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: @Chris I have increased Virtual memory but still the crash happens on windows 7 SP1 OS. But the application works fine without any change in jre or xmx value modification.