# Configure Netbeans to compile and run different jvm

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm

Does anyone know how to configure Netbeans to compile a project with 64 bits Java Platform and run it with a 32 bits Java Platform?  Both jvms are the same version.

Comment: Are you using native libraries? Otherwise, there should be no difference since bytecode is independent. (http://stackoverflow.com/q/783662/422353)

Comment: Bytecode might be independent, but the ability to load native code is not - the 64-bit JVM will choke if you try to load a 32-bit native code library.