# how to run java project created in 32 bit in 64 bit in windows 8

Tags: java, windows, operating-system, project, 32bit-64bit

I have developed a java project in 32 bit Os. I am unable to use it in 64 bit Os. Is there any solution for this?  My system is 64 bit windows 8 right now. I am unable to use the project here. Please help me.

Comment: Java classes do not have any idea of _bitness_. They can run with a Java 32bit system as well as with a 64bit system.

Comment: You question is much to unspecific to be answered. By its nature, Java programs should be independent of 32 vs 64 bit. What exactly is not working? Are you unable to invoke a 32 bit java.exe on a 64 bit system; is your application behaving unexpectedly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783662/java-32-bit-vs-64-bit-compatibility

Comment: Please elaborate - *I am unable to use it in 64 bit Os*. You are giving very little information

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem, we have backward compatibility. Things developed on 64 bits don't work on 32 since they are developed on newer apis but things developed on older version work smoothly since the never versions are backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Even Java in nature is built for platform independent programming, you can quickly turn your java program into a highly platform dependent one. For example, using native libraries, making OS specific file system operations. Try to avoid these and try to get rid of them.