# JavaFX: Build <32.bit>.exe file

Tags: java, javafx, build

I'm developing a JavaFX-Application which should be able to run on 32bit and 64bit machines.
**My developing environment:** 
  - Windows7 (64bit)
  - Luna(4.4)
  - JDK 1.8.0_65

> For building my project I'm using (ant) build.xml. How can I accomplish, building from a 64bit machine a 32bit **.exe** file???

Comment: If you're using the [standard JavaFX packaging tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/) to build a self-contained application, I believe it can only build native executables for the platform on which you're running (it includes the current JRE in the executable). So you would need to build the 32-bit exe on a 32-bit machine and the 64-bit executable on a 64-bit machine (and a Mac OSX .dmg on a Mac, and a .rpm on an appropriate linux machine, etc etc).

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

> Java bytecode (and source code) is platform independent, assuming you use platform independent libraries. 32 vs. 64 bit shouldn't matter.

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783662/java-32-bit-vs-64-bit-compatibility)

just use 32 bit(86x) java se version and you will not face any compatibility problems. By the way ant is very old school. I recommend use Maven or Gradle. Good luck

Comment: That's only true for building jar files. It's not true if you're building a [self-contained (i.e. native) application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGIBBCI) which must include the correct JRE for the target platform.