# Can I run 64bit java program on a 32bit windows os

Tags: java, windows

Can we run a Java program which uses 64bit datatypes like `long` and `double` on a Windows 32bit machine?

Comment: 64bit datatypes and a 64bit Java program are not the same thing, and the answer is yes.

Comment: Its not clear yet to me. Please point me to a good resource to understand better.

Comment: I'd do a google search, that should point you to many resources.

Comment: @DilipKumar [Java 32-bit vs 64-bit compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/q/783662/1248974), https://www.quora.com/Can-Java-code-compiled-using-64-bit-jdk-run-on-32-bit-jre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. A java program is an intermediate byte code and not platform dependant. There is no such thing like "64 bit java program". But the JVM which runs the java program is of course platform dependant. On a 32bit machine you have to use a 32bit JRE or JDK, and vice versa.

See also [java-32-bit-vs-64-bit-compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783662/java-32-bit-vs-64-bit-compatibility)

Comment: There are two questions, which one did you answer?